# How can I efficiently update a table based on other rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with this column (among others):

```
id int identity(1,1) not null
```

I've added a column to store the approximate date the record was inserted:

```
insertdate smalldatetime null
```

I've filled in the `insertdate` where I can using the earliest reference found in forensic searches of related tables and logs. This does, however, leave a number of NULL "gaps" in the data, as well as situations where a record with a lower ID number has a more recent `insertdate` value than subsequent ID values.

The `identity` attribute provides an adequate basis to assume that a record must have been created before any record with a higher `ID` value, so I've decided to update the `insertdate` for any record where it is null or a subsequent ID has an earlier date:

```
UPDATE
table
SET
insertdate = (SELECT MIN(insertdate) 
      FROM table t2
      WHERE
        t2.id >= table.id 
        AND t2.insertdate IS NOT NULL
      )
```

Unfortunately, updating like this is eating the server's lunch... 1 hour and counting for 2.5 million records.

Any ideas for how to do this more efficiently?

It only needs to be done once, but this is a production server, so I'd prefer to not lock up the table for any longer than necessary.

Comment: There is of course a default set on this column for new records. But the table is over 10 years old and the insertdate column is new, so I'm attempting to determine approximate insert dates for  *existing* records based on what I can piece together from other tables.

Comment: Thanks @Blam, typo, fixed it.

Comment: You could help it a bit by adding an index on id,insertdate (that would save some bookmark lookups), but you might want to break it into smaller updates (WHERE table.id BETWEEN @n and @n+100), in a loop that increments @n by 100 at a time.

Comment: Follow-up note: the *fastest method by far* was to create a temporary table with ID and earliestdate from the main table and compare/join to it. This required truncating and re-populating the table for each pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will help but you don't need to test for null.
Min() will not consider nulls.

```
UPDATE
table 
SET
insertdate = (SELECT MIN(t2.insertdate) 
                FROM table t2
               WHERE t2.id >= table.id 
                 AND t2.ID < table.id + 10000)
```

Could you limit to the next x rows?
Is there a point at which you are pretty sure you are not going to find a smaller date?

And you could limit table and t2 to the ID of the first row when you set a default on date.

Might fill up the transaction log and roll the whole thing back.
If that happens just be patient and let it roll back.
If you abort it now it is going to have to roll back.
Breaking up in batches of 100,000 is going to let the transaction log clear.

Comment: Limiting the number of rows updated and the number of rows searched is a good strategy, and I'm getting some progress made 100,000 rows at a time searching a window of 5,000 higher IDs apiece. Accepting this answer.